# Troubles with finding closest point on a plane to the origin

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

I have a trouble with the coordinates of a point on the plane that is closest to the origin

The equation of the plane is $5x-7y+z=-21$

The book I am using uses the formula $\vec{OR}=\vec{OQ}+\vec{QP}_\vec{n_u}$ where Q is the point outside the plane, P is a point belongs to the plane and $\vec{n_u}$ is the unitary normal vector of the plane.

As a result, I calculated as following:

- P(0,0,-21) and unitary normal vector $\vec{n_u}=[\frac{5}{\sqrt{75}},\frac{-7}{\sqrt{75}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{75}}]$
- $\vec{QP}$ = (0,0,-21)-(0,0,0)= (0,0,-21)
- $\vec{QP}_\vec{n_u} = \frac{|\vec{QP}\cdotp\vec{n_u}|}{1}\vec{n_u}$
- $(\frac{7}{5},\frac{-49}{25},\frac{7}{25})$

However, first of all the result I obtained does not belong to plane $\pi$, secondly, the answer key gave the answer of $(\frac{-7}{5},\frac{49}{25},\frac{-7}{25})$ which belongs to the plane as well

**The only way, as far as I am concerned, is if $\vec{n} = [-5,7,-1]$, which in the case the equation would be totally different, and result in a different plane**

I am not sure where I did wrong, **because I have checked again that I am using the right formula** so I assume I made mistakes in calculations?

Comment: You’ve made a simple sign error. Recompute the projection onto the normal.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I have no idea how I could make such mistake even using calculator.

Answer (score 2):

Note, the line that passes through origin and is normal to the plane is

$$x=\frac{5t}{\sqrt{75}},\>\>\>y=\frac{-7t}{\sqrt{75}},\>\>\>z=\frac{t}{\sqrt{75}}\tag 1$$

Substitute above in the equation of the plane $5x-7y+z=-21$ to obtain $t=-\frac{21}{\sqrt{75}}$. Plug it into (1) to obtain the point on the plane,

$$(-\frac{7}{5},\frac{49}{25},-\frac{7}{25})$$

Comment: @Yan Zhuang - why do you have P(0,0,-21), which does not seem relevant

Answer (score 1):

The line connecting a point off the plane to the nearest point on the plane will be perpendicular to the plane. So the direction vector of that line will be parallel to the normal vector of the plane.

$$ \vec{v}=\lambda\mathbf{N} $$

So the equation of a line through the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ off the plane and perpendicular to the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ will be

$$ (x,y,z)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)+ \lambda(a,b,c)t$$

Since $(0,0,0)$ is not on the given plane, we know that the line containing it and the near point $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ on the plane satisfies

\begin{eqnarray} (x_1,y_1,z_1)&=&(\lambda at,\lambda bt,\lambda ct)\\
&=&(5\lambda t,-7\lambda t,\lambda t) \end{eqnarray}

and that

\begin{eqnarray} 5x_1-7y_1+z_1&=&-21\\
5(5\lambda t)-7(-7\lambda t)+\lambda t&=&-21\\
75\lambda t&=&-21\\
\lambda t&=&-\frac{7}{25} \end{eqnarray}

So

$$ (x_1,y_1,z_1)=(-\frac{7}{5},-\frac{49}{25},\frac{7}{25} )$$

Notice that the value of $\lambda$ is inconsequential. You should get the same answer regardless of the value of $\lambda$.

Comment: Okay, I understand your way of solving this, but did you see any error in my steps? Because this formula is suggested by the textbook with which I solved many other questions without error, and we are expected to use this formula during the exam as well

Comment: Actually, I am having a bit of difficulty determining what your steps were and what $O$ is. I presume that $R$ is the near point to the origin.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought this is a universal formula. Then don't worry, I will ask the teacher regarding your method. After all, it is he who mark the paper, so it is important that I just present him this method. Thank you very much!